# How to hide a particular text in a heading tag that has common same tag for many texts

Tags: jquery, css

The h4 tag is automatically generated by an application in a page. So, I don't have any control over it to manually to change the tag from h4 to other like h5 h6 etc.... Also there is no Title or Name or ID preceding to this tag.
The following is the code in the same page: 
Update: it is in between form tag.

```
<h4 class="heading4">Apple Pulp</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Orange Juice</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Kiwi fruit</h4>
```

In the above h4 tags, how to hide 'Apple Pulp' alone in CSS or Jquery or whatever best suitable. I request someone to help me. If it can be done  with CSS alone, it would be great, as some people may switch off Scripts in browsers. Thanks
This is just an example and it need not necessarily the second one to be hidden. I wanted to hide even the first one on one page. I edited it by adding another text with space. Sorry about the heading tags modified with two words with  space.
I have modified the question because all the answers are working in this enivironment and I thank all for answering fantastically, but it not working in my php page. Expecting modified answer from you all. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to hide specifically "Orange" header? or is that an example?  *how* do you want to select which one to hide?  Is it always the **second**?  Is it based on the **text**?

Comment: freedomn-m You have asked a right question to me. I have modified  my question for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for updating to confirm it's an example - however, it's still not clear how you decide in each scenario which one you want hidden.  If you know the position (1st, 2nd, 3rd etc) you can use my answer below (`:nth-child`) substituting the correct index/position.  If it's based on text, then use @Satpal 's answer.

Comment: freedom-m   I want to add the hide-code manually in each particular page with particular heading that needed to be hidden. Will the space in between "Apple Juice'" make any difference in working of the hide-code or answers given here?

Comment: You can use @Satpal's code - use the `.filter` version if you want the text to match exactly - change "orange" in that answer to "apple juice".  An alternative is to hide them all and then *show* the others, so you don't get FOUC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the second h4 by using css `:nth-child`, eg:

```css
h4.heading4:nth-child(2) {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="heading4">Apple</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Orange</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Kiwi</h4>
```

Comment: freedom-m . Excellent your code is that worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:contains()` selector to `.hide()` the element.

```js
$(".heading4:contains('Orange')").hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="heading4">Apple</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Orange</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Kiwi</h4>
```

---

For exact match use `.filter()`

```js
$(".heading4").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim().toLowerCase() === 'orange'
}).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="heading4">Apple</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Orange</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Kiwi</h4>
```

Comment: Satpal. Thank you, but somehow it didn't work in my php page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("h4").eq(1).hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="heading4">Apple Pulp</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Orange Juice</h4>
<h4 class="heading4">Kiwi fruit</h4>
```

Comment: Vicky patel. Your code also worked. Well done!. But I chose freedom-m 's code because of CSS. I Would be glad to use your code in another senario.